# How to install/replace on Android without using Eclipse

Tags: android, command-line, installation, apk

A buddy sent me a later version of an .apk file. I already had the earlier version on my device.

When I tried to adb install the file, I got this:

```
$ adb install ../FlashLite.apk 
320 KB/s (18311 bytes in 0.055s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/FlashLite.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]

$ adb uninstall FlashLite.apk
Failure

$ adb uninstall /data/local/tmp/FlashLite.apk
Failure
```

How do you install/replace from the cmd line? I don't have the source, so I cannot do it from Eclipse.

Comment: If you are having real problems, then *adb shell* into your phone and delete the apk manually. After that you should be able to reinstall as before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

delete the old version from your phone under settings->applications->manage applications and then the install should work.

Answer (score 81):

When you uninstall you have to specify the java path to the activity.

```
adb uninstall com.haseman.myapp
```

where my main activity is at src/com/haseman/myapp/LaunchActivity.java

further, you can do a replace install with

```
adb install -r myApplication.apk
```

Commonly, however, replacing a build will fail if the same key isn't used to sign both the apk on the phone and the apk you want to install.  If you see an error "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES" you need to uinstall the app first and then install it.

Comment: Yup.. this makes more sense in the context of the question

Answer (score 35):

You have to use `adb uninstall [packagename]`, for instance, `adb uninstall org.vimtips.supacount`.

This the package name listed in your manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.vimtips.supacount"
    android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="0.1.5">
```

Comment: This is a much more useful answer than the one that was marked correct because on my phone, the app simply wasn't showing up in the menu to be removed... so I was really stuck.  Thanks Synic.

Comment: Not to mention so much easier than tapping through all those menus!

Comment: check to make sure you match the casing of package name.  typically it is all lower, but it may not uninstall with the command line if the case doesn't match.

Answer (score 24):

You need to supply the -r key:

```
adb install -r myapp-release.apk
```

This has been already discussed:
    [Why does adb install <same-packagename-always-release> fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053791/why-does-adb-install-same-packagename-always-release-fail)

Comment: Supposing the app was signed with same key, I would vote this answer as accepted

Comment: hint: also -d for device installation over emulator

Answer (score 0):

delete the old version from your phone under settings->applications->manage applications
Then you can install by cmd line or upload it to a website and directly download it to the phone

Comment: my problem is it disappered from my phone. I can't uninstall it and I can't install a new version.