# Why does adb install <same-packagename-always-release> fail?

Tags: android, apk, adb

I know that `adb install` will not replace an existing package if it's of a different build *type* (i.e. debug vs. release).

Eclipse also successfully replaces the debug apks whenever I run a debug session.

But when I attempt `adb install` for replacing an existing *release* apk with another release apk (same package name!), I get a failure message:

```
adb install myapp-release.apk 
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/myapp-release.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
745 KB/s (34310 bytes in 0.044s)
```

Wasn't that supposed to work? What am I missing?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I suppose if the app is already installed, you need to supply the `-r` key:

```
adb install -r myapp-release.apk
```

From the `adb` help:

```
'-r' means reinstall the app, keeping its data
```

Comment: Note that you can use the -r flag even if the package doesn't exist, so you may as well always use it unless you don't want to override an existing apk.

Comment: its not work! I should manually remove previous version before install new one