# How to update the pre-installed application using ADB command ?

Tags: android, adb

I have tried with **adb install -r**  but its not working at all . I dont want to update through Google Play Store. **Android OS version is 4.0** and device isn't rooted .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2525717/5515371

Comment: Not working with adb install -r as i mentioned. anybody has tried with pre-installed app ?

Comment: Tried uninstalling your app first

Comment: check your logcat..what's the error you are getting

Comment: by `pre-installed application` you mean `system application`, which can't be uninstalled?

Comment: yes its system application.

Answer (score 2):

If `adb install -r` not working, then it indicates your apk is not the update to the pre-installed one in your device.

`adb install -r` should work for updating apks signed with same keystore.

Comment: Does it replace new database with install -r option ? or does it only update existing app only ?

Comment: Update existing app only